# Unify Jenkins checkout on different agents

Tags: jenkins, checkout

I have approximately the following jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
    agent {
        label "agent1"
    }
    
    parameters {
        booleanParam defaultValue: false, description: 'Make clean build', name: 'CLEAN'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            steps {
                script{
                    if (params.CLEAN){
                        cleanWs()
                    }
                    checkout scm
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Debian build") {
            agent {
                label "debian"
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.CLEAN){
                        cleanWs()
                    }
                    checkout(changelog: false, scm: scm)
                }        
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I added `skipDefaultCheckout` so a user can decide to make a clean before checkout or not.
I noticed though that `checkout scm` lines can theoretically checkout different code because   they start at different time.

I think if I simply let Jenkins to checkout on it's own they will be the same and share the actual timestamp of checkout.

Is there a way I can have this functionality and still be able to do a clean checkout based on the parameter?

[Jenkins help page is here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup)

Comment: why you do multiple checkout and on different agent?

Comment: This is out of scope I think why I need two or more agents. Simply Jenkins allows me to do so and default checkout will checkout the same if used multiple times implicitly. But  if I want an optional clean build - I can't